# X.Org Nouveau display Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, system

Im running Ubuntu 16.04 on my Asus G55VW 15" ROG Laptop. When i use the X.Org driver which is default my system runs fine, ive got a hdmi port and screen which has a naitive res of 2560x1080 which is widescreen. It is currently set to 1920x1080 so it looks a little weird.

When i use any of the Nvidia legacy drivers i cant get it to use 2560x1080 so i switch to NVIDIA Binarydrivers either 304.131 or 361.42 and i can get the resolution and looks great but sporadically locks up the machine. Or when i boot it GUI doesnt start correctly

Its not due to the screen being used because when im at work just on the 15" built in using the NVIDIA binary it still occasionally locks up.

Anyone else experience this? I used to use the latest NVIDIA on 14.04 and never had an issue so its weird its starting now.

I an provide logs etc but just from a user experience perspective i wanted to see if anyone else has had similar issues?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I thought I'd share that this thread worked for me in case anyone stumbles across this question.

[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Thanks!